# Symfony2 js validation based on annotations

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

I'm trying to create a good validation js <=> Symfony2, I came up with the collection of all the errors and creating a path to id form elements and everything looks it is working properly, including relationships and collections forms, my question is whether you can do something nicer? Symfony can have a bundle for that? which will be much more useful  than my piece of code?

//in controller

```
        $ajax = $request->request->get('ajax');
        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid() && !$ajax){

        } elseif($form->isSubmitted() && !$form->isValid() && $ajax){
            $serializer = $this->get('serializer');
            return new JsonResponse(array(
                'valid' => false,
                'errors' => $serializer->serialize(
                    $form->getErrors(true),
                    'json')

            ));
        }
```

// and in js

```
$('form[name="product"]').on('submit',function(){
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    data = data + '&ajax=true';
    $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: Routing.generate('shop_add_products', { slug: $(this).data('slug') }),
            data: data
        })
        .done(function( msg ) {
            //there i must write check if errors then not return false and allow normall process form
            $('input,textarea,select').parent().removeClass('has-error').find('span.help-block').remove();;
            var errors = JSON.parse(msg.errors);
            var filteredErrors = [];
            var mappedErrors = [];
            for(var k in errors){
                filteredErrors[errors[k].messageTemplate] = errors[k].message;
                var selector;
                var path = errors[k].cause.propertyPath.split('.');
                if(path.length == 2){
                    selector = 'product_' + path[1];
                } else {
                    var path1 = path[0].replace('children[','');
                    path1 = path1.replace(']','');
                    var path2 = path[1].replace('data[','');
                    path2 = path2.replace(']','');
                    selector = 'product_' + path1 + '_' + path2 + '_' + path[2];
                }
                var helper = '<span class="help-block">' + errors[k].message + '</span>';
                $('#' + selector).parent().addClass('has-error').append(helper);
            }
        });
    return false;
});
```

**How to valid files sending via ajax and mapping it to this function?**
[See there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40391433/symfony2-how-to-validate-files-sending-via-ajax)

Comment: What about the Validator already available in Symfony : https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/validation.html

Comment: Yes i use annotations as validation but my ask is how to create a good validation without "refreshing" the page.
I build my code that sends form to the controller and if has errors return json response with array of errors then i fetch this array and map errors into form fields that works fine but i ask for better way to do that

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, it seems obvious now. I haven't try it though : https://github.com/formapro/JsFormValidatorBundle