# Symfony2 how to validate files sending via AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, validation, symfony

Hi today i must make a validation for files(there images) sending via ajax, i have huge problems with validation as annotation that work only when we send normaly form! not if files data coming via ajax :/ then that is code for symfony that can valid our collection of files and set error messages to their propertyPath.

```
$validatorImage = new Image(); // Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Image
$validatorImage->mimeTypesMessage = 'image.mimeTypesMessage';
if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($form->get('images') as $image) {
        $errorList = $this->get('validator')->validateValue(
            $image->get('file')->getData(),
            $validatorImage
        );

        if (count($errorList)) {
            foreach ($errorList as $error) {
                $image->addError(
                    new FormError(
                        $error->getMessage(),
                        null,
                        array(),
                        null,
                        array('propertyPath' => 'children[images].data['.$i.'].file')
                    )
                );

            }
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
```

// is valid etc.
our js action like similar to this one:

```
  $('form[name="product"]').on('submit', function () {
        var _self = $(this);
        var data = _self.serialize();
        data = new FormData(_self[0]);
        data.append('ajax',true);
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            });
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can validate your entity without a form builder. Just know that `validator` is a service itself. You can use similar to something below in your `controller` :

```
// Collect data from ajax .
if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
    $data = $request->get('data');
    $files = $request->files;

    // Prepare your entity, Know you haven't uploaded image yet.
    $image = new Image();
    $image->setFile($files['image']);

    // Call your validator to validate Image Entity.
    $validator = $this->get('validator');
    $errors = $validator->validate($image);

    $errorMessages = array();
    if (count($errors) > 0) {
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            $errorMessages[] = $error->getMessage();
        }
    }

    // send response to ajax accordingly. $errorMessages has all the errors as string.
    $response = array();
    return new JsonResponse($response);
}
```

**Note** : Variables and objects might be different for your use cases.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply, i test and rząd it again when i come back to home.                      $request->isXmlHttpRequest()  this is a way to check if form is submited by ajax?

Comment: Yes, That will return true, if the form is submitted via ajax.